# The correlated subquery in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel a little bit confuse about the correlated subquery in MySql.
For instance, I have tables as follows:

```
rental is (customer_id, inventory_id)
inventory is (inventory_id, film_id)
film_category is (film_id, category_id)
category is (category_id, name) #There are 12 categories in this table.
```

I wonder which customer(s) has rented at least one film in every category?

Then I typed such code and return zero values. But in fact there are exactly 19 values which satisfy the above condition.

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM rental NATURAL JOIN(
    SELECT film_id
    FROM inventory NATURAL JOIN(
        SELECT f1.category_id
        FROM film_category AS f1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            (SELECT category_id
            FROM category)
            except
            (SELECT category_id
             FROM film_category AS f2
             WHERE f2.film_id = f1.film_id)
            )
        )AS T1)AS T2
```

Thanks for you guys advice, the sample data I am using as follows(paritially)

rental:

| rental_id | inventory_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 367 | 360 |
| 2 | 1525 | 459 |

inventory

| inventory_id | film_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

film_category

| film_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 11 |

category

| category_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | action |
| 2 | animation |

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), Please post the SQL as text

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: You forgot to share the query you are using. Also, if it does not return the values it should, share sample data

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I have uploded the code, actually our teaching assistant has told me that the f1 and f2 in my code are totally the same. And that's also the reason why my query is failed. But I don't know how to correct it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a homework assignment, I would like to provide a little bit more details.

Step 1. For SQL queries, the first step is to visualize the data model, which is the blue-print of the rental business. From your description, the data model may look like this (you need to validate it against the database that you have access to. Mainly about tables, primary keys and foreign keys (relationships))

[image]

Step 2. Use the data model diagram to navigate and to identify all the data items you need. In this case, you would need:

- `rental` (`customer_id`, `inventory_id`),
- `inventory` (`inventory_id`, `film_id`),
- `film_category` (`film_id`, `category_id`).

You shouldn't need `category` table because you it's captured in `film_category` table.

Step 3. develop the query to get a list of `customer_id` who rented films in all 12 categories.

```
-- the reason to use count(distinct ...) is to resolve duplicates if exists
select r.customer_id,
       count(distinct fc.category_id) as category_count,
       count(distinct i.film_id)      as film_count,      -- unique film count
       count(distinct r.inventory_id) as inventory_count
  from rental r
  join inventory i
    on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
  join film_category fc
    on i.film_id = fc.film_id
 group by r.customer_id
having count(distinct fc.category_id) = 12;  -- exactly 12 categories
```

The above should get you started and the correct solution depends on the database design that you need to verify. If you need customer count, use the above query as subquery to `select count(customer_id) from ...`